# php form not showing output?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

when i click the submit button nothing happens,the page simply reloads.shouldnt the page give me the $str that i created??? .i am new to php, i dont know error handling with sql.the connection is properly set with the database

```
<?php
//config file contains the creation of connection variable $con
require 'config/config.php';

$case_no="";


if(isset($_POST['submit button'])){
   $case_no = strip_tags($_POST['cs_no']); //Remove html tags
   $fname = str_replace(' ', '', $case_no); //remove spaces
   $_SESSION['cs_no'] = $case_no; //Stores first name into session variable

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM case_details WHERE cs_number='$case_no'");
//fetching and storing info from table into variables
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$filed_by=$row['filed_by'];
$defender=$row['defender'];
$district=$row['district'];
$status=$row['status'];
$details=$row['details'];
$date=$row['next_hearing'];
$updates=$row['updates'];

$str="<div class='case_body'>       
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>case no: $case_no</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>filed by: $filed_by</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>defender: $defender</td>/
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>district: $district</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>status: $status</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>cse details: $details</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>next_hearing:$next_hearing</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>updates:$updates</td>
       </tr>

    </table>

    </div>";
    echo $str;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>enter your case no here and click on the button for further information</h3>

<form action="case_status.php" action="POST">
    <input type="text" name="cs_no" placeholder="enter case no" >

    <input type="submit" name="submit_button">
</form>
```

here is the table details:-
id int-autoincreament, 
cs_number-int, 
filed_by-varchar, 
defender-varchar,
district-varchar,
status-varchar,
detailstext, 
next_hearing-date, 
updates-text

Comment: Try changing action="POST" to method="POST".

Comment: even after changing method="POST" the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the underscore in `if(isset($_POST['submit button'])){}` it should be `if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){}`.

Also try changing `action="POST"` to `method="POST"` in your form.

And please escape user inputs properly with [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or (preferred) prepared statements.